# How do I get a Pine or Linux email domain name to use a registered domain name from the internet?

Tags: linux, email, domain

I have a domain name on the internet that is registered with Godaddy.  I know how to set up Pine or different email programs on Linux servers (e.g., from a VPS).

How do I configure Pine (or some open source Linux email program) to have the email domain of my registered domain name?

Comment: Which mail server are you using? Is your mail server reachable through that domainname?

Answer (score -1):

you have to configure some mail server to handle mail for your domain, and put information about it in your domain configuration (MX field). for your convenience you can also add domains like imap.(your-domain) and smtp.(your-domain). then you configure pine as usual :)